# Как правильно составить подобный запрос SQL запрос в YII2?

Tags: yii, yii2

Как правильно составить подобный запрос **SQL** запрос в **YII2**?

**Внимание: Запрос должен быть защищенным.**

Нежен такой запрос:

```
SELECT getname FROM `customer` WHERE `id` = 123
```

Но этот запрос подобен :

```
$customer = Customer::find()
    ->where(['id' => 123])
    ->one();
```

---

этому

```
`SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `id` = 123`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id = 123; 
$customer = Customer::find()
            ->select(['getname'])
            ->where('id = :id', [':id' => $id])
            ->one();
```

Comment: больше спасибо за ответ. А не подскажете, как с этим работать? А то я для занесения данных в БД, использую экземпляр класса `class Account extends  \yii\db\ActiveRecord`   и уже в модели я его создаю, и добавляю так данные `$model2 = new Account();
$model2->login = $this->login;
$model2->save();`

Comment: А как получить данные из `$customer`?

Comment: Для добавления данных в БД, экземпляр **ActiveRecord** модели обычно создается в экшинах контроллера и передается во вью, например, в виджет **ActiveForm** (если нужна форма). А данные загружается с помощью `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` в контролере. Это не единственный вариант. Тут можете почитать подробнее https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru

Comment: Спасибо! Всё уже)

Comment: Атака SQL не пройдет через эти методы?

Comment: Через приведенный мною пример не пройдет

Comment: А почему у нас она не пройдет , там она экранируется?

Comment: Да, а вот тут ничего не экранируется: `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '. $id;
  $model = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryRow();`

Comment: Ну понятно, этот метод доступ к БД в Yii2 на более низком уровне. Просто немного беспокоит одно, будет ли yii2 успевать за обновлением чистого php, включая методы экранирования, которые тоже обновляются и устаревают.